# How to access Boolean flag into remote Java Class

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on a JavaFX application which will have several tab panes which I want to set to visible or hidden using check box which will send boolean flag to render or not to render the component.

***Check box***

```
final CheckMenuItem toolbarSubMenuNavigation = new CheckMenuItem("Navigation");
    toolbarSubMenuNavigation.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e)
        {

            // call here the getter setter and send boolean flag
            System.out.println("subsystem1 #1 Enabled!");
        }
    });
```

***Tab pane which will listen for the boolean property:***

```
public boolean renderTab;

public boolean isRenderTab()
{
    return renderTab;
}

public void setRenderTab(boolean renderTab)
{
    this.renderTab = renderTab;
}

tabPane.setVisible(renderTab);
```

The check box and the tab pane are isolated into different Java Classes. I need to send the value of the flag every time when I check or uncheck the flag. Can you tell me how I can send the flag using getter and setter?

***EDIT***

I tested this code:

```
final CheckMenuItem toolbarSubMenuNavigation = new CheckMenuItem("Navigation");
        toolbarSubMenuNavigation.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                boolean dcd = toolbarSubMenuNavigation.isSelected();

                DataTabs nn = new DataTabs();
                nn.setRenderTab(dcd);
                // call here the getter setter and send boolean flag
                System.out.println("subsystem1 #1 Enabled!");
            }
        });
```

and

```
public boolean renderTab;

    public boolean isRenderTab()
    {
        return renderTab;
    }

    public void setRenderTab(boolean renderTab)
    {
        this.renderTab = renderTab;
    }
```

But it's not working when I switch the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Inorder to get that eithr you need to have a intance or you need to create new intance there.

If you create a new object there it will create a fresh intance,which doesnt helps you any more..

I guess the only way you have is to Make the `renderTab` as a static field  and access there.

Comment: I updated the post. Can you show me some code sample about your idea?